Vega zooming and panning on beeswarm chart
Is it possible to create zooming and panning effect with the  beeswarm chart that uses force transform ?
For example https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/beeswarm-plot
I am trying to replicate this effect from the example list, the scatterplot, but with no success.
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/selection_translate_scatterplot_drag.html
Can you give me some example codes that allow zoom and pan in such visualization

You can pan and zoom this force directed graph here: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase?tab=readme-ov-file#force-direct-graph-dynamic

